# Mudar coluna de date para timestamp

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, data

Tenho uma tabela com uma coluna do tipo `date` mas preciso ver a informação do GMT, minha ideia é converter ela para `timestamp`. Como posso mudar isso mesmo que a coluna já contenha valor?

```
create table PRO_TFESTIVO
(
  oid_festivo      NUMBER(10) not null,
  fecha_hora_envio DATE to TIMESTAMP
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Voce nao pode alterar o tipo de uma coluna DATE/TIMESTAMP sem:

1. Renomear a coluna (Ex: OLD_FECHA_HORA_ENVIO) com os valores existentes;
2. Criar uma nova coluna com o nome original (FECHA_HORA_ENVIO);
3. Preencher essa nova coluna com os valores existentes na tabela renomeada;
4. Remover a coluna (OLD_FECHA_HORA_ENVIO), pois nao iremos mais utilizar ela;

**Converter de DATE para TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE:**

```
ALTER TABLE pro_tfestivo RENAME COLUMN FECHA_HORA_ENVIO TO OLD_FECHA_HORA_ENVIO;
ALTER TABLE pro_tfestivo ADD FECHA_HORA_ENVIO TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
UPDATE pro_tfestivo SET FECHA_HORA_ENVIO = FROM_TZ(CAST(OLD_FECHA_HORA_ENVIO AS TIMESTAMP), 'GMT');
ALTER TABLE pro_tfestivo DROP COLUMN OLD_FECHA_HORA_ENVIO;
```

**Extra :) Converter de TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE para DATE:**

```
ALTER TABLE pro_tfestivo RENAME COLUMN FECHA_HORA_ENVIO TO OLD_FECHA_HORA_ENVIO;
ALTER TABLE pro_tfestivo ADD FECHA_HORA_ENVIO DATE;
UPDATE pro_tfestivo SET FECHA_HORA_ENVIO = CAST(to_timestamp_tz(OLD_FECHA_HORA_ENVIO, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ssXFF TZR') at time zone 'GMT' AS DATE);
ALTER TABLE pro_tfestivo DROP COLUMN OLD_FECHA_HORA_ENVIO;
```